# Radio and Check box functionality

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile.

Please find the following code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var count = 1;
        var newSet = '<div data-role="fieldcontain">' + 
            '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">'+
             '</fieldset></div>';

        $(function (){
            $('.cbDiv').append(newSet);
        }) ;            

        $(document).on("click", ".add", function() {                        
            newSet = newSet += '<input type="radio" name="radio' + count + '" id="radio' + count + '" value="radio' + count + '" />' + 
            '<label for="radio' + count + '">radio' + count + '</label>';
            $(".cbDiv").html(newSet);           
            count++;
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
        <div data-role="content">
            <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Radio Button" />
            <div class="cbDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I dynamically adding the radio buttons in jquery mobile. It works fine..
but, its not working as radio button (ie. single selection). It working as a check box.(ie. Multiple selection).

How to prevent this?

Also the style has not applied.

Answer (score 0):

With radio buttons you will need to give the `name` attribute. If you give each box the same name, then it will behave as single selection instead of a checkbox. In your case, they name attribute changes with every radio button. You should remove the number from it and it should work as expected.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94MzH/) shows how it works.

The style should apply if you use the proper classes and CSS selectors. If it doesn't, you add the wrong class or you have a mistake in your CSS.

Edit: I see you use `radio` as `id`. You should probably have this as `class` instead, since `id` should only be used for a single element on a page.